# Converting differential pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

I need to submit a lab report.
I've measured:

- Differential pressure [Volts]
- Flow rate [Hz]
- Flow Rate [m^3/s]

In my report I need to get the Pressure Differential in Pascal but how can I convert Volts to Pascal?(?!?!?!?!?!)

How do the measuring devices can measure pressure in volts and flow rate in Hz in the first place?

Thank you!

Image for demonstration:
[image]

Comment: Calibrate the sensors against known values of pressure - the lab has a barometer etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device will contain a pressure transducer.

**transducer**
*noun*

> a device that converts variations in a physical quantity, such as pressure or brightness, into an electrical signal, or vice versa.

In your case it is converting pressure into a voltage.

> ... but how can I convert Volts to Pascal?

You read the manual for the device and find the conversion factor which will be in volts/pascal or pascal/volt. (Note lowercase for SI units named after a person. The symbols are capitalised.)